# Why do I get "abort" on this program?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Lets tallk about the next code sample:

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable
#include <deque>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;
std::deque<int> queue;



void Inserter()
{
    int count = 10;
    while (count >= 0)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        queue.push_back(count);
        --count;
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

void Consumer()
{
    int count = 10, got;

    while (count >= 0)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        if (!queue.empty())
        {
            got = queue.back();
            queue.pop_back();
            std::cout << "We got: " << got << std::endl;
            --count;
            lock.unlock();
        }
        else
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(Inserter);
    std::thread t2(Consumer);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program I get "abort" but I shouldnt.
The only reason I see here to get abort is when I leaves locked lock without opened it - but there is no any reason for a lock to stay locked because after every loop I passes I open the lock.

What do you see the reason is?

Comment: Did you _try_ stepping through your code, with a debugger?

Comment: Getting an "abort" is not a specific description. Do you trigger an assertion in standard library, do you cause an access violation, ...?

Comment: If this is Visual Studio press Debug when the dialog appears and then walk up the callstack to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call `std::thread::join` in the main program.  When `t2` goes out of scope, you call its destructor, and because you haven't  joined the thread, it causes an abort.

Incidentally, you don't need to call `lock.unlock()`.  The whole point of `std::unique_lock` is that it will do that automatically when the object is destructed.  (And it would be much cleaner to declare `got` right where you get the value out of the queue.)

So your code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <deque>

std::mutex mtx;
std::deque<int> queue;

void Inserter()
{
    for (int count = 10; count >= 0; --count)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        queue.push_back(count);
    }
}

void Consumer()
{
    for (int count = 10; count >= 0; )
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        if (!queue.empty())
        {
            const int got = queue.back();
            queue.pop_back();
            std::cout << "We got: " << got << std::endl;
            --count;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(Inserter);
    std::thread t2(Consumer);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The requirement to call `join` is because a common idiom is to make `Inserter` be a class derived from `std::thread`, and have the `Inserter` constructor pass a suitable thread function to the `std::thread` constructor.  If the class contained member variables which the thread method accessed, it would be bad if the thread method kept running after the object was destructed.  The standard requires you to avoid this by either calling `join` (in which case the thread method has finished), or by calling `detach` (in which case it is your responsibility to make sure you don't access variables which have gone out of scope).

Comment: You right. It works now. but what reason does it have for destruct itself? The t2 thread done his work before the main done (I have cin that stops the main from out of scope)

Comment: Does my paragraph explain?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the  issue you need to call `std::thread::join` on your both threads

```
int main(){

       std::thread t1(Inserter);      
       std::thread t2(Consumer);
       t1.join();
       t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Demo : [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80632c9206157bf1)